# Is it possible to perform multiple separate replacements with a single regular expression?

Tags: regex

If I have the string `aab12a221b1` and I want to replace it with `zzy12z221y1` (i.e. replace `a` with `z` and `b` with `y`), is it possible to do that with a single regular expression? Two separate expressions would be trivial (`/a/g -> z`, `/b/g -> y`), but I am looking for a method to accomplish this without having to run more than one regex. So far I have been unable to find any way to do this.

Specifically, I am using [grepWin](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/grepWin.html) to do some replacements across a large amount of files, and there are four characters I need to replace with other characters. The amount of time it would take to run four instead of one is minimal and I'm not on a time limit, so this is more of a hypothetical question than anything else.

Comment: @Fede I'm pretty sure it's not possible; I haven't found anything helpful through searching and I don't really know how it would be implemented if it was possible. Only asking to make sure there's not some obscure hack or workaround I've missed.

Answer (score 1):

This may not solve your particular problem, but generally speaking it is possible - if you can use perl regular expressions - to pass captured groups as arguments to functions for the replacement, using the `e` modifier.

```
%map = ("a", "z",
        "b", "y");
sub get_mapping{
   return $map{"$_[0]"};
}
$str=~s/([ab])/get_mapping($1)/eg;
```

Example running here: http://ideone.com/nVJTXk

Comment: Very neat. Unfortunately not helpful in my case, but thanks nonetheless.